# SynchronizationContext.Send,what is SendOrPostCallback?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, delegates, synchronization

VB.NET 2010, .NET 4

This might be a dumb question but I'm wondering what is special about the `SendOrPostCallback` delegate that is the first argument in `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`'s `Send` and `Post` methods?  In other words, I can do the following:

```
SyncContext.Send(Sub() ..some work.., Nothing)
```

And that works (`SyncContext` is a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` object).  Why might it be preferable to do:

```
Dim blah As Threading.SendOrPostCallback = Sub() ..some work..
SyncContext.Send(blah, Nothing)
```

?

Update:  Acknowledging Hans' answer, I update the question:  If there is no difference, why is `SendOrPostCallback` defined?  Is there something special about it or is it just an alias?  Perhaps I'm just not getting something more fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, it is just a delegate like any other.  There's no logical difference between the snippets, the JIT compiler generates the same code.  Pick the style you prefer.

Comment: Well then, why have a thing called `SendOrPostCallback`? (question updated)

Comment: It's not a thing, it's a type.  A delegate type.  Why do types have descriptive names?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.  It's just a name for a thing that defines the type of subroutine/function that the `Send`/`Post` methods can take for their first argument?  It's essentially a name for the rule?

Comment: Yes, that's what delegate types are all about.

Comment: @Brian: A delegate needs a name in order to be part of a member signature. At the time `SynchronizationContext` was introduced (2.0), it was considered best practice to give delegates specific, descriptive names. These days, it's more common to use the generic delegates that were greatly expanded by 4.0, and I think `SendOrPostCallback` would be likely called `Action<object>` if it were redesigned today.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense to me.  Thank you both for helping me understand.